# Can Hazelcast queries work with object methods?

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, spring-el

I couldn't find this in the documentation.

If I have a complex object in a hazelcast cache:

```
public class MyObj {
    private int something;
    private AnotherObject complexMember;
}
```

Can I do:

```
map.values(new SqlPredicate("something > 3 AND complexMember.someProperty > 3"));
```

I know that the `@Cachable` annotation uses [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html) where this is possible. Is it possible to do it programmatically somehow ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes possible. Try following;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(null);
    final IMap map = hz.getMap("test");
    map.put(1, new MyObj(1, new AnotherObject("value")));

    System.out.println(map.values(new SqlPredicate("something > 0 and complexMember.someString like 'val%'")));
}

static class MyObj implements Serializable {
    private int something;
    private AnotherObject complexMember;

    MyObj(final int something, final AnotherObject complexMember) {
        this.something = something;
        this.complexMember = complexMember;
    }
}

static class AnotherObject implements Serializable  {
    private String someString;

    AnotherObject(final String someString) {
        this.someString = someString;
    }
}
```